# How to add file handlers in Apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, configuration

I moved a website from another server to mine and there is a PHP file with .ph extension. On other server it worked fine, but not on the new one. It just tries to download the file in question, instead of sending it through PHP parser.

Obviously it's about file handlers, so I need to add .ph extension to be handled as .php file. I thought this was trivial, but still couldn't do it :) It has somehow changed in Apache2 and I can't seem to figure it out.

I've tried to set the handler in mime.conf and in /etc/mime.types. Nothing so far.

Due to the app complexity, I wish I wouldn't have to change the extension of the file. Could someone point me to the right direction? This shouldn't be this hard :)

I'm running Apache 2.2.17 and PHP 5.3.5 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that I had this definition in my /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

The regexp pattern expected either p3 or tml ending to .ph -  prefix.

The easiest fix was just to add:

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

into the file. Works like a charm now.

Comment: How can I add PHP to deal with files that do not have any extension? Is there a "DefaultHandler" directive? In Apache 2.2.29, with PHP 5.5, the following does not work:  `DefaultType application/x-httpd-php`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this after modifying mime configuration

> service apache2 restart

or edit your httpd.conf

**Updated & tested:**

```
AddHandler type-map var
AddHandler php5-script .ph
AddType text/html .php
```

Comment: Nope. At least adding `AddType text/html .ph` makes it stop to try to download the file in question, but no; it still won't parse it.

Comment: already added into my test server and restart apache. it parse .ph and content php echo "HELLO WORLD" into HELLO WORLD only.

Comment: i'm not add any MIME type. can you remove mime type and try again?

Comment: Got it. But thanks for your help.